# not getting the customToken when trying to signInWithEmailAndPassword in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

from the below image in firebase docs they are saying that when user sign to app send their sign-in credentials with username(email) and password, they said that response will contain a custom token but for me in the response only showing access token and refresh token, if we use any of these two token for `signInWithCustomToken` getting an error of invalid token, please pull me out of this issue

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding this. For custom auth, you are typically using your own auth system and not Firebase. Following the docs, they assume you are using your own username/password auth system. In that case, you send both to your backend server. You verify the credentials (username, password) in your own auth system. If they are legit, you lookup the user id in your auth system database, you then use the Firebase Admin SDK `createCustomToken(uid)` to mint a custom token with that uid. You send it back in the response to the client. The client will then call `signInWithCustomToken` to complete the sign-in.